# LiveData Mvvm - How can I send more than one type with LiveData? I'm trying to send the object and also the adapter position to update

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm using LiveData with MVVM. After updating my database with Room, I am trying to sendback both the `Object` I inserted into my Room database, and also the adapter position. In my ViewModel class, the method is:

```
private MutableLiveData<String> insertItemLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>;
```

```
public void insertMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem, int adapterPositionToUpdate){
     repo.insertOrder(menuItem.getId())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Integer integer) {
                        //The order is successfully inserted into database
                        //So I return back the name of the inserted order

                        String s = "Inserted Item: " + menuItem.getNameOfOrder();
                        insertItemLiveData.setValue(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        errorLiveData.setValue("Failed to cancel order.");
                    }
                });
}
```

In the on success method, it returns the String I want to display, but I also want to update the position of the `Recyclerview item` that has changed. What is the best way to handle this situation?

I can use a wrapper class and have setters for a String and the adapter position, but I feel like there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: There is no Other way which is better than a Wrapper `Object` . For Usual scenarios Like an API call we mostly use a wrapper [maybe like this one](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/vo/Resource.kt) . I think that will cover your case String type message and `Interger` type data . make sure it should not mess your architecture of Resource Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

A resource wrapper is a good idea for it.[MVVM Resource Wrapper With Live Data](http://%20https://github.com/Kashif-E/MvvmPopularMoviesAppWithDarkMode) you can check my code to get an insight on how to use it